# Multiple Alias Routes to base Razor Page

Tags: razor, .net-core, routes, razor-pages

I'm pretty new to Razor Pages, and I'm trying to figure out how to replicate routing I have in my current Angular Page.

I have a base razor page that will be populated with different data depending on which parameter is passed to it. This is easy enough, and I know how to do this. However, my problem is in the routing because I want to be able to pass a readable parameter that is based off of the base URL. For example, I want to be able to do:

https://myURL/Band1
https://myURL/Band2

and have both point to the same page (but not the Index Page), consume the parameter "Band1" or "Band2" to display the associated information.

I understand how to consume the parameter, and how to get data, what I'm not clear on is how to do this routing based on the base URL. I can see how I'd do it if it were https://myURL/b/Band1 since I'd make a "b" page and accept parameters.

But how does one do this without that intervening segment of the URL? I need to be able to do this to not break existing links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for Razor Pages suggest you can create a page named `Index.cshtml`, which will act as the default where no page is specified in the URL.

**Edit**
If you want to preserve the parameterless index page, but have your page take its place when the additional URL part is provided, try the following in your page:

```
@page "/{bandName}"
```

Comment: I do have an index page, but I want that to be a different page than the one indicated by Band1, Band2. MyURL should land on one page. MyURL/Band1 and MyURLBand2 should land on the same page, but not Index.

Comment: I will give that a try! That seems like the solution!

Comment: Yes, that's the solution! Thanks for the answer! If I could upvote, I absolutely would!